# Java error: bad operand types for binary operator in HashMap

Tags: java, integer, int

I was trying to count the occurrence of each character in a string (contains only lowercase letter). I built a HashMap with all character initialized to 0. When updating, I met the error.

The code is:

```
private static HashMap<Character, Integer> addToMap(String s) {
    HashMap dict = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        dict.put((char)('a' + i), 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        dict.put(s.charAt(i), dict.get(s.charAt(i)) + 1);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: post the error message

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]!

Comment: you could probably use a `String` as the key for the hashmap instead of `Character`. Unless there's a reason why.

Comment: Your type for `dict` is raw.

Comment: Change `HashMap dict = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();` to `HashMap<Character, Integer> dict = new HashMap<>();` - you have it backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed types you wanted to use to parametrize the map. It should be:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> dict = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: This [makes the errors go away](http://rextester.com/CQMQ63042).

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I stuck at the dumb mistake for 2 hours!